Vault deployment with S3 Storage failing
I was trying to deploy Vault with S3 Storage using following manifest , S3 bucket is in us-west-2
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: vault-config
  namespace: backend-shared
  labels:
    app: vault
data:
  config.json: |
    {
      "listener": [
        {
          "tcp": {
            "address": "0.0.0.0:8200",
            "tls_disable": true
          }
        }
      ],

      "storage": {
        "s3": {
          "bucket"     : "vault-qa-storage"
          "region"     : "us-west-2"
          "access_key" : "***"
          "secret_key" : "***+***+p"
        }
      },

      "ui": true,
      "api_addr"         : "http://0.0.0.0:8200"
      "max_lease_ttl"            : "10h"
      "default_lease_ttl"        : "7200h"
      "cluster_name"             : "vault"
      "raw_storage_endpoint"     : true
      "disable_sealwrap"         : true
      "disable_printable_check"  : true
    }

---

kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: vault-policy
  namespace: backend-shared
  labels:
    app: vault
data:
  policy.json: |
    path "root-ca/issue/*" {
      capabilities = ["create", "read", "update"]
    }

---

kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: vault
  namespace: backend-shared
  labels:
    app: vault
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: vault
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: vault
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: vault
        image: vault:1.13.3
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command: ["vault", "server", "-config", "/vault/config/config.json"]
        securityContext:
         capabilities:
           add:
             - IPC_LOCK
        env:
          - name: VAULT_ADDR
            value: 'http://127.0.0.1:8200'
          - name: VAULT_API_ADDR
            value: 'http://127.0.0.1:8200'
          - name: VAULT_TOKEN
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: vault
                key: root-token
          - name: VAULT_KEY
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: vault
                key: unseal-key
        volumeMounts:
          - name: vault-config
            mountPath: /vault/config/config.json
            subPath: config.json
          - name: vault-policy
            mountPath: /vault/policy/policy.json
            subPath: policy.json
        ports:
          - name: vault
            containerPort: 8200
      volumes:
      - name: vault-config
        configMap:
          name: vault-config
          items:
            - key: config.json
              path: config.json
      - name: vault-policy
        configMap:
          name: vault-policy
          items:
            - key: policy.json
              path: policy.json

But getting following error
Error initializing storage of type s3: unable to access bucket "vault-qa-storage" in region "us-east-1": AuthorizationHeaderMalformed: The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-west-2'
    status code: 400, request id: HM2B4QHRT135ABBG, host id: 7igfngKalcSYfNIZKP5egnPfaE8MP/9yUysRAGBMdorS/Tsyo+/u0Wt/y7zOq6YG5luTR0+R0kE=

Any idea what I am missing ?

Can you cat the resulting config.json file and add it to your question? +Is the extra space at the end of your bucket name intended?

Can you try this in your json file ?
# HTTP listener
listener "tcp" {
  address = "0.0.0.0:8200"
  tls_disable = "true"
}

# Storage
storage "s3" {
  bucket        = "my-vault-bucket"
  region        = "region"
  access_key    = "*****"
  secret_key    = "*****"
}

ui = true
api_addr         = "http://0.0.0.0:8200"
max_lease_ttl         = "10h"
default_lease_ttl    = "7200h"
cluster_name         = "vault"
raw_storage_endpoint     = true
disable_sealwrap     = true
disable_printable_check = true

